# Convert int to timestamp get hour in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

```sql
select sum(a) as count , HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(create_time)) as h  from alert group by h
```

`create_time` is like this `1600506000`. I don't know how to covert int to timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering 'Hour of the day' for **UTC date**. **One way could be.**

```
GET <indexName>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['create_time'].value * 1000).atZone(ZoneId.of(\"Z\")).getHour()"
        }
      },"aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "a"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```